# Technical reasoning behind Android SDK requiring a downloaded driver

Tags: windows, linux, macos, drivers

I've started down the path of tinkering with my Android phones. What's curious to me is that during the bootloader unlocking process if you're on Windows you are [required to download and install drivers](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/12/05/how-to-unlock-the-galaxy-nexus-bootloader/) while on OS X or Linux drivers are not required. Why is this?

Comment: Couldn't it be that Android uses an Ext filesystem that Windows doesn't support?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh I've seen Windows requires a driver even for a basic `adb` connection, and not just a generic serial-over-USB driver.

Comment: That sounds like Windows to me! Thats why I use my external hardware with Linux and OSX (too bad my backup disk is NTFS and that I already have backups on it. It could have been Ext4).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but [these directions from androidcentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-unlock-galaxy-nexus-bootloader) make no mention of the Samsung driver.

And looking at the bottom comments, it looks like some people do, some people don't.

My guess is it depends on your system configuration.

Comment: I've experienced this with multiple phones (HTC Evo 4g, Evo 3D and now my Galaxy Nexus). Samsung doesn't even offer the drivers referenced in my question for Linux or OS X, nor are they needed.